# Adding string to a model attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Straightaway. In my model I have a field `DistanceTravelled` , it is of type double. Now whenever i want to display it using `@Html.DisplayFor` helper method, then I want the distance travelled value to be appended by "Km". For Example:

**123 Km**  *instead of 123*

I can do that by placing Km at the end of `@Html.DisplayFor` helper. But I was hoping that there must be some data annotation attribute or some other simpler way.

Thanks for trying to help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0} km")]
public double DistanceTravelled {get;set;}
```

More info about the `DisplayFormatAttribute`: [DisplayFormatAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your ViewModel to something like this:

```
...
string DistanceTravelled {{ get { return String.Format("{0} km",this.DistanceTravelled; };set; }
...
```

But I think this won't work with your Doulble. Implicit convention between Double and string :(

Ok got it :)

In view model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
+
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0}km")]
double DistanceTravelled {get;set;}
```

and this code below for Id=2:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Id)
```

renders as

```
2Km
```

Comment: Good idea. Any idea with data annotations? DisplayFormat?